# Cut the portion of the line segment with knife tool in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

As shown in the figure the corner of following shape need to be removed to make it dashed line. I am trying to use **knife tool** to cut the portion of the line. But failed to do so. Is there any possibility to cut the part of the line tool?[image]

Comment: Scissor tool for stroked paths, Knife tool for Shapes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The knife tool won't work on an open path with a stroke. It only works on closed paths.

Example. The top line is an open path with a stroke. The bottom line is identical but has been Expanded to a closed path (outline) with a fill.

[image]

If you want a dashed line, it's probably easier to simply apply a dashed line to the stroke in the Strokes panel.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Billy. How do you answer in an animated way? May I ask please?

Comment: @python I use screen capture software called ShareX

Comment: thank you for sharing Billy.